# Using Google Analytics in readthedocs.org

Tags: google-analytics, read-the-docs

My project documentation is hosted on readthedocs.org at 
http://nsetools.readthedocs.org 
Is it possible to use google analytics with documents hosted on readthedocs? Since html is not generated by me, I am not sure where to apply the google analytics code snippet.

Comment: Looks like RTD have their own tracking code on the sites (https://github.com/rtfd/readthedocs.org/issues/199), but there doesn't seem to be a way to insert your own code.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this myself but see http://www.drmaciver.com/2015/04/getting-google-analytics-on-readthedocs/

> Go to the Admin page for your project,
>    Click on “Advanced settings”,
>    Enter your Google Analytics Tracking ID in the box at the bottom that says 'Analytics ID'

Comment: If you use a custom theme such as alabaster, you may need to add the ID to conf.py. See [alabaster theme options](http://alabaster.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customization.html#theme-options).

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

Put `googlea<id>.html` (from [Google Search Console](https://search.google.com/search-console/welcome)) into `docs/source` and add
`html_extra_path = ["googlea<id>.html"]` somewhere in `conf.py`, then verify using [Google Search Console](https://search.google.com/search-console/welcome).

### Steps

1. Go to [Google Search Console](https://search.google.com/search-console/welcome) and enter your read the docs URL in the URL prefix box: e.g. https://mat-discover.readthedocs.io/en/latest. Click *CONTINUE*.
2. Download the `googlea<id>.html` file and place it in `docs/source` (e.g. `mat_discover/docs/source`). Use [`html_extra_path`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-html_extra_path) inside of `conf.py` as follows (i.e. add the following line somewhere in `conf.py`):

```py
html_extra_path = ["googlea<id>.html"]
```

3. Inside the `docs` folder, run:

```sh
make clean
make html
```

and check to make sure `docs/build/html/googlea<id>.html` exists.

4. Commit, push, and wait for your RTD website to update (this could take a few minutes)
5. If you have the webpage from step 1 still open, click *VERIFY*, otherwise navigate back to [Google Search Console](https://search.google.com/search-console/welcome), and re-enter your URL (e.g. https://mat-discover.readthedocs.io/en/latest). If it worked, it should tell you so, and you can then "Go to property". Notice that https://.readthedocs.io/en/latest/.html brings you to a bland HTML page with only the text from the Google Analytics HTML file

Note: Everywhere mentioned, replace "<id>" with the actual ID that is shown from step 1, and "<my-website>>" with the name of your RTD site.

Comment: This doesn't work because the file has to be at the root of the domain, but RTD puts it behind `/<lang>/<version>/`.